# C++ spanish question mark

Tags: c++, windows, character-encoding

I am beginning developing in C++ and I am developing a simple calculator in console and when my program ask to the user if wants to exit,the character '¿' doesn't appear (The questions in spanish are between '¿' and '?')

Can someone help me?

PD: The problem only happens in Windows,not in Linux

EDIT: Here is the code that output the code:

```
cout << '¿' <<"Desea salir (S/N)? " ;
```

Comment: Please post the code that outputs the character.

Comment: Wild guess: whatever you output is incompatible with whatever terminal emulator you use.

Comment: Agreed, this probably comes from the encoding of the terminal emulator. Consider using Cygwin under Windows if you want to display UTF8 characters such as "¿".

Comment: More importantly, a) Are you using a computer running an English version or a Spanish version of Windows? Do you need to support both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to deal with this problem.

The fundamental problem is not that the `¿` doesn't exist in the console, but that the console and your C++ text editor disagree on what that character is. The two are using different character codes for many characters beyond those needed for English. Character codes 32-126 (letters, numbers, punctuation and brackets), are universally the same. However, character codes 128 through 255, which from a Spanish point of view includes all the accented characters, "u with diaeresis" (e.g. "pingüino"), Ñ, and the starting ¿ and ¡, depend on the specific environment.

Why have such an inconvenient disagreement in character codes is a historical accident, interesting on its own but out of the scope of this question. To keep it simple: in the Windows OS, "consoles" (typically) use the list of characters described in [OEM Code Page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), while Windows  applications like your C++ editor (typically) use the [Windows-1252 Code Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

There is no portable (universal) solution for this problem, because the issue of differing charsets is a platform-specific problem. Windows is unfortunately somewhat unique in that the editor and (console) outputs use different sets.

The first and simplest solution - which is fine for toy programs - is to just look up the character code that you want from the OEM 437 code-page, and use that. For `¿`, that's #168 (0xa8 in hex, or \250 in octal). You can just embed the character code in the string to make clear what you're trying to do, either of these:

```
std::cout << ""\x0a8""Cu""\x0a0""l es el primer n""\x0a3""mero?\n"; // hex
std::cout << "\250Cu\240l es el primer n\243mero?\n";  // octal
```

Outputs:

```
¿Cuál es el primer número?
```

Note how I had to do the same thing with the ú and the á. Unfortunately, writing strings like this gets unwieldy quickly. using macros or `const char`s can help, but not much.

A second alternative is to use a Windows function such as `CharToOemA`. For example<sup>1</sup>:

```
#include <windows.h>
...
...
char pregunta[] = "¿Cuál es el primer número\n";
char *pregunta_oem  = new char[sizeof(pregunta)/sizeof(char)];
CharToOemA(pregunta, pregunta_oem);
std::cout << pregunta_oem;
delete []pregunta_oem;
```

For a more complex program, I would wrap that pattern into a utility function or class.

A different approach is to change the Code Page of the console, so that it agrees with your C++ editor and the rest of Windows. You can do that via the CHCP console command, or via the SetConsoleOutputCP() function, but that doesn't work on the default "raster font" used by consoles, so you have to change the font as well. When the font is set to a unicode font like Lucida Console, this works:

```
std::cout << "¿Cuál es el primer número?\n"; // ┐Cußl es el...
UINT originalCP = GetConsoleOutputCP();
SetConsoleOutputCP(1252);
std::cout << "¿Cuál es el primer número?\n"; // ¿Cuál es el...
SetConsoleOutputCP(originalCP);
```

(I don't know if you can change the font from the program itself; I have to look that up. The standard way to do it from the console is to click on the tiny icon on the corner, click Properties, Font tab, and pick a font from the list).

---

1 *I have to warn that this snippet contains a number of subtleties that can easily trip a beginner. You have to make sure the source of the text is a char array; if you're using a char pointer, `sizeof` won't work correctly and you have to use `strlen(source)+1`. For the source I used the natural option of a char array initialized to a literal, but you can't do that for the destination because the contents of such an array are read/only. If you are using a new'd char array or one that is not initialized to a literal, you can use the same char array for the source and destination. This example feels very C-like.*

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`_setmode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw4k6df8(v=vs.80).aspx) function to do that :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#if defined(WIN32) && !defined(UNIX)
# include <io.h>    // for _setmode()
# include <fcntl.h> // for _O_U16TEXT
#endif // WIN32 && !UNIX

int main()
{
#if defined(WIN32) && !defined(UNIX)
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
  //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#endif // WIN32 && !UNIX

    std::wstring wstr = L"'¿' and '?'";

    std::wcout << L"WString : " << wstr << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

> To write UNICODE chars (assuming LE is the standard Windows variant of UTF-16...) out with the iostream library, call _setmode() with _O_U16TEXT and then use wcout.

But you can't use `cout` anymore. It throws an assert.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11236524/1394283) answer.

Comment: @Cako If it already works on linux and you have just just to fix it on windows, check my edit.

Comment: The compiler says that there is an error: C:\Users\Carlos\Documents\cpp\Calculadora\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\Users\Carlos\Documents\cpp\Calculadora\main.cpp|33|error: '_O_U16TEXT' was not declared in this scope|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using simple call to `std::cout`, you should be able to print Unicode strings, if you set your command line to Unicode mode:

**1. Change code page to UTF-8**

You can do this by simply calling the command below in your cmd:

```
chcp 65001
```

**2. Make sure you are using a font which has the characters you want to display**

Lucidia Console should do the trick, as it supports ¿ (and other characters included in [WGL4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Glyph_List_4)).

Comment: Yes,my Windows 7 is in Spanish

Comment: Note that setting the console codepage to 65001 (UTF-8) will break many console applications. You may try with `chcp 1252` instead. That will break only _some_ applications.

Answer (score 0):

this character is simply not included in basic ascii. Try using wstring http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/wstring/

Comment: The encoding of hist terminal emulator could be utf8, in which case std::string and std::cout could be just the right hing. But we don't know what he does and how he does it...

Comment: Exacly normal char range is -128 to 127.

Comment: Correction: #191 in Windows-1252 and #167 in OEM(437, aka DOS/US).

Comment: @Dzia, that is an artifact of C's `char` type being unsigned by default, irrelevant unless you are doing arithmetic. When it comes to code-to-character conversion, what matters is the bit pattern and how the host will interpret it. If you prefer to say that in Windows 1252 the character '¿' is -65, that's fine. It's still 10111111. Of course, that mapping is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [Ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/), symbol ¿ have the code 168. You can use in output stream \ddd to print some special character.

Comment: American Standard Code for Information Interchange (ASCII) has codes 0 to 127.  The ¿ referenced is listed in an _Extended ASCII Code_.  There are many variants of _Extended ASCII Code_.

Comment: I have tried it,but some pages says me that the code is 168 and others 191

Comment: @Cako, 191 is the code used by you c++ editor. 168 is the code used by the console. You have to use 168 to get it to show on the console.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the command console does not support non-ASCII characters by default (ASCII has mainly English language characters and few accented characters). To get support for characters in other character classes play around with the `chcp` command. Refer to it's documentation [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/chcp.mspx?mfr=true).

In your case I think you need to run `chcp 850` in the console before running your program.