# Mapped file not displaying info

Tags: c++, winapi, process, memory-mapped-files

I made 2 programs which you can find below.

The first one counts all the processes that have <3 threads and writes their name in a mapped file.

The second one is opened in the first's main function and should display what it finds in the mapped file. However, it doesn't and I think it's because nothing is written in it, but I can't seem to figure out why.

First:

```
#include "stdafx.h"


#include <windows.h>
#include <Tlhelp32.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

// http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/16820/
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298569/difference-between-mbcs-and-utf-8-on-windows
// http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76252/What-are-TCHAR-WCHAR-LPSTR-LPWSTR-LPCTSTR-etc
using namespace std;


void writeToFileMap(LPCTSTR msg)
{
    HANDLE hMapFile;
    LPCTSTR pBuf;
    TCHAR szName[]=TEXT("mapFile");


    hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(
        INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,    // use paging file
        NULL,                    // default security 
        PAGE_READWRITE,          // read/write access
        0,                       // maximum object size (high-order DWORD) 
        256,                      // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)  
        szName);                 // name of mapping object

    if (hMapFile == NULL)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Could not create file mapping object (%d).\n"),
            GetLastError());
        return ;

        pBuf = (LPTSTR) MapViewOfFile(hMapFile,   // handle to map object
            FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, // read/write permission
            0,                   
            0,                   
            256);     

        if (pBuf == NULL) 
        {
            _tprintf(TEXT("Could not map view of file (%d).\n"),
                GetLastError());

            CloseHandle(hMapFile);

            return ;
        }


        CopyMemory((PVOID)pBuf, msg, (_tcslen(msg) * sizeof(LPCTSTR)));
        _getch();           

        UnmapViewOfFile(pBuf);

        CloseHandle(hMapFile);

    }
}






void getProcessList()
{//snapshot la toate procesele din sistem
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    PROCESSENTRY32 proc32;

    TCHAR names[MAX_PATH]=L""; //wchar_t pentru ca folosim Unicode

    if(hSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        cout<<"invalid handle value error!\n";
        return;
    }

    //setez dimensiunea structurii
    proc32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    //get info despre primul proces(se va afisa in do...while)
    if(!Process32First(hSnap, &proc32))
    {
        cout<<"Tread32First() error!\n";
        CloseHandle(hSnap);
        return ;
    }

    //cauta in restul proceselor
    //daca nr. threaduri<3, introdu in fisierul mapat
    do
    {
        if(proc32.cntThreads < 3)
        {   
            //cout<<"Current process id(adica programul A): "<<GetCurrentProcessId()<<"\n";
            wcout<<L"Process Name: "<<proc32.szExeFile<<"\n";
            cout<<"Process ID: "  <<proc32.th32ProcessID<<"\n";
            cout<<"Thread Count: "<<proc32.cntThreads<<"\n"<<endl;

            //exclud procesul curent, nu vreau sa-l termin
            //includ celelalte procese in string, separate de newline
            if(GetCurrentProcessId()!=proc32.th32ProcessID)
            {
                lstrcat(names, proc32.szExeFile);
                lstrcat(names, L"\n");
            }

        }       
    }while(Process32Next(hSnap, &proc32));

    //afisez
    wcout<<names;

    //scriu in fisierul mapat
    writeToFileMap(names);

    //inchid handle la snapshot
    CloseHandle(hSnap);
}

int main(void)
{
    //scriu in fisierul mapat procesele
    getProcessList();


    //deschid al doilea proces care va citi din fisier si inchide procesele
    STARTUPINFO startupinfo ;
    startupinfo.cb = sizeof (startupinfo) ;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pinfo ;
    memset(&startupinfo, 0, sizeof (startupinfo)) ;
    if(!CreateProcess(L"Tema2CSSO.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, false, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
        NULL, NULL, &startupinfo, &pinfo))
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Eroare la create process (%d).\n"),
            GetLastError());

    }
    // Wait until application has terminated
    WaitForSingleObject(pinfo.hProcess, INFINITE);


    getchar();
}
```

Second:

```
    /*Creati 2 programe: 

1. Primul va enumera toate procesele din sistem care au mai putin de 3 fire de executie si le va 
transmite, printr-un fisier mapat in memorie, programului 2 
 2. Al doilea program, la initializare, isi va seta privilegiul SE_DEBUG_NAME si va omori toate 
procesele transmise de programul 1. 
*/

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define BUF_SIZE 256
TCHAR szName[]=TEXT("mapFile");


int main()
{
   HANDLE hMapFile;
   LPCTSTR pBuf;

   //deschid fisierul mapat
   hMapFile = OpenFileMapping(
                   FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,   // read/write access
                   FALSE,                 // do not inherit the name
                   szName);               // name of mapping object 

   if (hMapFile == NULL) 
   { 
       std::cout<<"Could not open file mapping object.\n";
      return 1;
   } 

   //asociez un handle
   pBuf = (LPTSTR) MapViewOfFile(hMapFile,  // handle to map object
               FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,         // read/write permission
               0,                    
               0,                    
               BUF_SIZE);                   

   if (pBuf == NULL) 
   { 
       std::cout<<"Could not map view of file.\n"; 

      CloseHandle(hMapFile);

      return 1;
   }

   //inchid procesele
   MessageBox(NULL, pBuf, TEXT("Process2"), MB_OK);

   UnmapViewOfFile(pBuf);

   CloseHandle(hMapFile);

   return 0;


}
```

Comment: The first process closes the MMF handle before you start the second process - by the time it tries to read it, it's already gone.

Comment: Ran it without closing the handle and still doesn't print.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc If the first program terminates without closing the handle, Windows closes it for you. Try to add a `Sleep( INFINITE )` after the CopyMemory in the first prog.

Comment: Decided to add everything to my main function and it worked. Not using functions is annoying, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code after work:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"



#include <windows.h>
#include <Tlhelp32.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

// http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/16820/
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298569/difference-between-mbcs-and-utf-8-on-windows
// http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76252/What-are-TCHAR-WCHAR-LPSTR-LPWSTR-LPCTSTR-etc
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{   //snapshot la toate procesele din sistem
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    PROCESSENTRY32 proc32;

    TCHAR names[MAX_PATH]=L""; //wchar_t pentru ca folosim Unicode

    if(hSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        cout<<"invalid handle value error!\n";
    }

    //setez dimensiunea structurii
    proc32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    //get info despre primul proces(se va afisa in do...while)
    if(!Process32First(hSnap, &proc32))
    {
        cout<<"Tread32First() error!\n";
        CloseHandle(hSnap);

    }

    //cauta in restul proceselor
    //daca nr. threaduri<3, introdu in fisierul mapat
    do
    {
        if(proc32.cntThreads < 3)
        {   
            //cout<<"Current process id(adica programul A): "<<GetCurrentProcessId()<<"\n";
            wcout<<L"Process Name: "<<proc32.szExeFile<<"\n";
            cout<<"Process ID: "  <<proc32.th32ProcessID<<"\n";
            cout<<"Thread Count: "<<proc32.cntThreads<<"\n"<<endl;

            //exclud procesul curent, nu vreau sa-l termin
            //includ celelalte procese in string, separate de newline
            if(GetCurrentProcessId()!=proc32.th32ProcessID)
            {  // sprintf(pids,"%d",proc32.th32ProcessID);
                lstrcat(names, proc32.szExeFile);
                lstrcat(names, L"\n");
            }

        }       
    }while(Process32Next(hSnap, &proc32));//cat timp mai sunt procese in snapshot

    //inchid handle la snapshot
    CloseHandle(hSnap);

    //afisez string-ul de procese
    wcout<<names;

    //scriu in fisierul mapat
    HANDLE hMapFile;
    LPCTSTR pBuf;
    TCHAR szName[]=TEXT("Global\\mapFile");

    //il creez
    hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(
        INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,    // use paging file
        NULL,                    // default security 
        PAGE_READWRITE,          // read/write access
        0,                       // maximum object size (high-order DWORD) 
        256,                      // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)  
        szName);                 // name of mapping object

    if (hMapFile == NULL)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Could not create file mapping object (%d).\n"),
            GetLastError()); 
        return 1;
    }

    //fac fisierul utilizabil
    pBuf = (LPTSTR) MapViewOfFile(hMapFile,   // handle to map object
        FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, // read/write permission
        0,                   
        0,                   
        256);     

    if (pBuf == NULL) 
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Could not map view of file (%d).\n"),
            GetLastError());

        CloseHandle(hMapFile);
        return 1;

    }

    //scriu in el
    CopyMemory((PVOID)pBuf, names, (_tcslen(names) * sizeof(TCHAR)));

    //deschid al doilea proces care va citi din fisier si inchide procesele
    STARTUPINFO startupinfo ;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pinfo ;
    ZeroMemory( &startupinfo, sizeof(startupinfo) );
    startupinfo.cb = sizeof(startupinfo);
    ZeroMemory( &pinfo, sizeof(pinfo) );

    //creez noul proces
    if(!CreateProcess(L"b.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, false, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
        NULL, NULL, &startupinfo, &pinfo))
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Eroare la create process (%d).\n"),
            GetLastError());
        return 1;

    }
    // blochez A pana se termina B
    WaitForSingleObject(pinfo.hProcess, INFINITE);

    //unmap
    UnmapViewOfFile(pBuf);
    //inchid handle la map
    CloseHandle(hMapFile);

    getchar();
}
```