# How to convert a Qt project back to Multi-Byte version?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a third party project that is configured as `Multi-Byte` (all the Win32 functions resolve to their `...A` versions).

Now, after adding `Qt` support, the project setting changed to `Unicode` (all the functions NOW resolve to their `...W` versions). This change made compilation problems, because in the source code all the functions are explicitly defined with an `A` suffix.

Now, when I change the `Character Set` from `Unicode` (in the project settings) to `Multi-Byte` as originally, this doesn't do anything! All the functions are still resolved to their `...W` versions!. Why doesn't changing this setting cause appropriate resolving behavior (to resolve to `...A` versions)? How to painlessly convert the project back to the `Multi-Byte` version?

Comment: May be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13011256/4641116

Comment: If the source explicitly uses the A or the W versions of system calls, then that source has decided that it wants a specific version. That makes them independent of the project settings. There is no "painless" way to get around that.

Comment: @BoP Ok i but if the stetting changing from `Unicode` to`Multi-Byte` DO WORK then even if there is **explicitly** defined `A` version i'll work nicely because all the **implicit** definitions would resolve to `A` instead of `W`! Is't it!?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/127105/how-to-change-qt6-windows-appliaction-defaulting-to-unicode) is helpful.

Comment: QString stores internally texts as UTF-16 and so does Windows API. That might be was a bad decision of both parties to not use UTF-8 instead but now it is done and decades of work of innumerable developers has relied on it. One can want to make Qt's Windows platform integration to convert text to-from UTF-8 to use A version of API (that is anyway likely a converting wrapper around W version of API), but it is then unknown what will break. Who will supposedly debug and fix it?

Comment: 1) Always use W-versions of WinAPI functions explicitly; 2) Don't use A-versions of WinAPI functions; 3) Don't rely on `UNICODE` macro (i.e. project settings)

Comment: @Darros99 - If some code uses A functions explicitly, and others get them through the Multi-Byte setting, that would work. But if some other parts have coded the W-version explicitly, then you will have a problem. The project setting only affects the calls using the generic names, not the explicit one.

Comment: Why would you *not* want unicode?